# Relative height AND sticky footer with flexbox

Tags: css, height, flexbox, sticky-footer

I'm trying to craft a bootstrap layout matching these criterias:

- a sticky footer
- unknown heights
- inner content divs with relative min-heights (i.e. min-height 50 %)
- no JS if possible

  ```
  // HTML    
      <body>
        <div id="container">
          <header></header>
          <div id="content">
            <div style="background:red;"></div>
            <div style="background:green;"></div>
            <div style="background:blue;"></div>
          </div>
          <footer></footer>
        </div>
      </body>

  // SCSS
      header,footer{
          height:50px;
          background:grey;
      }
      html, body{
        height:100%;
      }
      #container{
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          min-height: 100vh;
          height:100%; // if added, #content>div is broken. If removed, sticky footer is broken.
          & #content{
              flex:1;
              height:100%;
              & div{
                height:50%;
              }
          }
      }
  ```

I also have a fiddle over there : https://jsfiddle.net/yakou32/706z8o80/12/

I can manage to have a sticky footer or a relative inner content, but not both simultanously...

Comment: if You already using `vh` can't You just use `div{ height:50vw;}`. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/706z8o80/13/)

Comment: Yes, of course. Making a mashup of different sources, I just lost consistency, and missed that ;) Thanks for your help. Would you like to answer on this one? Also, `height:100%`are useless.